# Composer Rest Authentication

Tags: angular, typescript, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger-composer

Recently, I created a multi user composer rest server. I was able to generate token and authenticate the user using angular/Typescript as client side app. My confusion is, is it possible to get the identity of the user who is signing in to the system? I will use the identity to limit the access of the user as defined in .acl file.

Here is the flow:

1. User signs in (supposed successful login)
2. Get the created identity of the User in step 1.
3. Use the identity to do the operation that the user is allowed to do as defined in .acl file.

Hope my question makes sense and understandable. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you execute a `GET` on `http://localhost:3000/api/system/ping` you should get back the Participant and the Identity similar to this:

```
{
  "version": "0.19.9",
  "participant": "org.acme.mynetwork.Trader#t01",
  "identity": "org.hyperledger.composer.system.Identity#bb79ab64833c147852d11e1f52432b9fa902f5c2e778576500be14f2f8934a8b"
}
```

If I understood the question this is what you wanted.

Comment: Does it mean also that the retrieved identity using that request will be the one that will be used in any request to the api?

Comment: Yes, that is the ID (and participant) that will be used -  until you switch to a different card in the Wallet, or authenticate with a different user through your passport stragegy.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any idea how can I switch an identity based on the person being authenticated?